# Jmeter beanshell sampler writing multiple lines

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter(5.1.1) script, I am trying to write into a csv file using BeanShell PostProcessor.

[image]

Where beanshell code is,

```
var name = "name";
var email = "email";
var currtime = "${__time(d-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss)}";
f = new FileOutputStream("D:/Temp/Temp.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(currtime + "," + name + "," + email);
p.close();
f.close();
```

It works but writes 3 lines in Temp.csv.

```
15-Nov-2020 05:16:32,name,email
15-Nov-2020 05:16:33,name,email
15-Nov-2020 05:16:34,name,email
```

Where only one line is expected to be written in CSV. Please suggest how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Beanshell PostProcessor is located on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level, it means that it's being run after every [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/)

   If you want it to be executed after a certain Sampler - move the PostProcessor to be the child of this sampler
   2.[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.
2. If you run your test with >1 thread (virtual user) each user will be writing the lines into the same file and in case of concurrent writing you will face data corruption and/or loss due to the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so I would recommend considering switching to [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) instead.